# How do I setup reverse proxy on nginx to avoid the CORS issue for my ionic and meanjs application.

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cors, meanjs

So I have 2 apps running on same server. 
1. On backend I have Mean.js which provides the services to perform CRUD operations. 
2. On front end I'm using IONIC app which provides the UI experience.

Front end ( Ionic app )  is running on 81 and Backend on 3000.

I tried to setup reverse proxy for backend ( node/ mean ) by looking up online but didnt succeed.

Here's my nginx setup

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name meantodo.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved it by adding following lines on  https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/config/lib/express.js#L57

```
var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://34.192.250.412:80',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
  };
  app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the header to your express app allowing the ionic server ip and port like so:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://yourIonicServerIp:port');
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
      next();
  });
```

Comment: where in the mean app do i do this ?      https://github.com/meanjs/mean           config/lib/express.js in line 50ish..  I'll tell you if it works.

Comment: I think its working but let me check for other similar apis too...  Thx FRECIA

Comment: Hope it does, let me know if you get any error, happy coding!

Comment: can i do it for more than 1 url i.e like   ,   app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin);  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://234.34.23.112:81');  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://234.234.34.34.112:81');
          next();
      });

Comment: READ operation works fine, but I still getting the Issue  when updating:    Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403      @FRECIA

Comment: I think it didnt worked in the first place,         ionic.bundle.js:25005 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://34.192.250.112:81:3000/api/properties. Cross origin requests are only supported for    protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: what do you mean  bundle isn't using http ?      Do you mean angular's $http ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Ionic and mean.js, but it sounds like you're running into the same thing I was, with a React set-up of 2 sites, where one calls another with a POST or GET.

So, first, you said your front-end site is on port 81, but it says it can't load `http://34.192.250.112/api/properties` in the error.  That's a port 80 call.  And you say your backend that's servicing queries is on 3000, so are you sure your operations aren't actually on that 3000 site?  You'd need to put either a `:81` or `:3000` after the `112`, as appropriate, if that's in some "GET" your aren't sharing.  Or maybe it's doing that because of that `listen 80`, so you'd have to replace that with `listen 81` or `listen 3000`, as applicable to where your apis really are.

But assuming you fix that in your call and then run into a similar error, again, you'd need to go to IIS on the web server, assuming it was hosted there (if not in IIS, I'm sure there's an equivalent place in Tomcat or whatever you're using for where I'm about to tell you to go).  On the site you're trying to call, open the **HTTP Response Headers** feature.  Add:

```
Name:  Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Value  http://34.192.250.112:81
```

If your request requires authentication, you may need to add:

```
Name:  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
Value  true
```

Additionally, if that's not enough, and you still get errors, you can launch Chrome with security disabled, then navigate to your site and do the operation that causes your "GET".  On a command prompt, you do:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=C:/somefolder
```

Then navigate to your site.